# ag-grid is not allowing for me to drag columns into the row group within the control panel

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am having an issue with dragging columns within my control panel, into the row groups pannel also in the control panel. Below are my gird options and default column behavior.

```
 gridOptions={

    floatingFilter: false,
    animateRows:true,
    columnDefs:this.columnDefs,
    groupMultiAutoColumn:true,
    groupHideOpenParents:true,
    suppressMakeColumnVisibleAfterUnGroup:true,
    suppressAggFuncInHeader:true,
    suppressMenuHide:true,

    suppressColumnVirtualisation:true,



    autoGroupColumnDef:{
        resizable: true,
        filterValueGetter: function(params) {
          var colGettingGrouped = params.colDef.showRowGroup;
          var valueForOtherCol = params.api.getValue(
            colGettingGrouped,
            params.node
          );
          return valueForOtherCol;
        },

      }
  };
```

```
 this.defaultColDef = {flex: 1,
    minWidth: 125,
    maxWidth:500,
    sortable: true,
    filter: true,
    enableRowGroup: true,
    enablePivot: true,

    enableValue:true,

    cellFilter: 'number: 2',
    resizable:true,
    menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab', 'generalMenuTab', 'columnsMenuTab'],
    sortingOrder: ['asc','desc', 'null'] ,

    allowedAggFuncs: ['sum', 'avg', 'count'],
  };  this.aggFuncs = {
    sum: this.sumFunction,
    avg: this.avgAggFunction,


  }; this.sideBar = {
    toolPanels: [
      {
        id: 'columns',
        labelDefault: 'Columns',
        labelKey: 'columns',
        iconKey: 'columns',
        toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
        toolPanelParams: { suppressSyncLayoutWithGrid: true },
      },
    ],
    defaultToolPanel: 'columns',
  };
```

Currently, when I grab a column I get waring stopping Icon. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Due to me setting the ZOOM property in css to 90%, the grid did not orientate properly and the columns I would drag in would not trigger the row grouping.